# How do I install Gosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I downloaded a course from iTunes U that teaches Ruby. We have reached a section in the coursework that creates a paddle video game. The instructor mentions that gosu must be installed but does not share how.

I believe I have download gosu 0.7.50 but I do not know how to install it.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a gem - just `gem install gosu`.